# Can I use [(ngModel)] in a <li> or <a> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs-ng-model, angular2-ngmodel, ngmodel

A beginner in angular2. A documentation of ngModel in angular1 stated that it can be used with ,  and . Does this apply to the ngModel usage with 2 way data binding in angular2 too ? or can it be used with elements like

and . What is the alternative if I need to use it within these tags if not directly. Please help.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#two-way

Comment: I guess you are aware of two way binding in angular 2 but you are asking if we can use that in li or a elements right? If this is what you are looking for . the answer is no we cannot . For such a scenario you have to use div element and for a tag use [src] . Hope this is what you were looking at

Comment: Hey Rahul. Yes that was exactly my doubt. Thanks for clearing it. btw can you if possible give a code snippet for this alternative usage ? will find it extremely helpful. Thanks again was really a great help.